# Recordset Addnew modifies first record in a table

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm currently having problems with adding a new record in a table through VBA in Access. The VBA is used through a Button in a Form which has 2 Combination fields and 2 date fields.

```
Private Sub Schlussel_hinzufügen_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim R As Recordset
    Set R = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Schluesselhistorie")
    R.AddNew
    ' Normally data is added to the record between these two
    R.Close
    Me.Requery
    DoCmd.Close
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Couldn't save record!", vbCritical
End Sub
```

As soon as the R.AddNew is called the first record of the table is modified with the Data from the combination and date fields. A completely new record at the end of the table is created as well when

```
R![SLH_Schluessel_ID] = Me.Kombinationsfeld13.Value
R![SLH_Kontakt_ID] = Me.Kombinationsfeld15.Value
R![SLH_Datum_Ausgabe] = Me.SLH_Datum_Ausgabe.Value
R![SLH_Datum_Rueckgabe_Soll] = Me.SLH_Datum_Rueckgabe_Soll.Value
R.Update
```

is called though. I am kinda irritated as the former (first row event) shouldn't happen as I know and when code is added above both the first row is modified and a new record with these values is added.

The table is externally linked and the field names are in German.

Are there restrictions to the DAO where the Recordset used can't specify which line the Addnew should use. Or does the Addnew take the values of the Form to automatically add the Values to the table?

Comment: What/where is your "first row event"?

Comment: if you are using a bound form then I'd guess that when you change your first record it will, of course, change the corresponding record in your table regardless of how you have your VBA written.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the recordsetclone of the form:

```
Private Sub Schlussel_hinzufügen_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim R As DAO.Recordset
    Set R = Me.RecordsetClone
    R.AddNew
    ' Normally data is added to the record between these two
    R.UpDate
    R.Close
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Couldn't save record!", vbCritical
End Sub
```

Comment: This could be doing something totally different though. Maybe I mis-read but can we guarantee the form is bound to `Schluesselhistorie` equally?

Comment: We don't know, but the `SLH` prefix of the field names indicates this.

Comment: I'm going to show off some Google translate foo here and make a guess: `hinzufügen` means `add` and `historie` is `history` so maybe the OP is trying to make an audit table? Maybe some data macros/triggers are in order, or maybe they are already being used which is causing the confusion.

Comment: Oh yes, lots of guessing is possible. Let's await some feedback from the questioneer.

Comment: I'm still trying to fix that problem, tough it has been a month already (with me being bedridden). The form is bound to Schluesselhistorie and I try to use a submit button for adding the record to the table. But while adding the record to the table, the data in the fields of the form are edited into the first row first. After that the record is added to the table without problems with the code above.

Comment: Then skip all that code, use `DoCmd.GoToRecord, , acNewRec` (to go to a new record) and assign your SLH values.